# Connecting ec2 instance with private ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpn

I have created a vpc and that is connected with internet and inside that VPC I have created an openvpn server on a ec2 instance and than connected it with my local machine. Now i am trying to do ssh using my private ip into openvpn server and it is not connecting.
Why i am not able to connect? anyone having any idea ?

Comment: Can you share the security group screenshot?

Comment: Did the VPN connection correctly establish? Does it say that the tunnel is UP?